# SharePoint 2013 Selected link not highlighted in quick launch and global navigation

Tags: 2013, quick-launch, top-navigation

I have a Dev and Prod environment. Everything is fine with Dev sites - selected links are highlighted in quick launch\top nav. But Prod sites do not reflect the same highlighting. I checked for publishing feature and they are activated. Is it that i missed one of the CU updates or something i need to check in the site. Please advise.